# A stop job is running for Advanced key-value store (X / no limit)

Tags: redis

so after installing redis onto my ubuntu 20.04 server. Whenever I reboot. A stop job appears for Advanced key-value store. I believe this is part of redis but I don't know why it keeps appearing and taking so long. How do I stop it

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue too and the fix was pretty simple.
You need to edit the redis service file defined by the command `systemctl show -P FragmentPath redis.service` :

```
$ systemctl show -P FragmentPath redis.service
/lib/systemd/system/redis-server.service
```

Look for the line that contains `TimeoutStopSec` and set it to the maximum value in seconds you want. I normally set it to 5 seconds.

After configuring the file, the line should look something like this

```
TimeoutStopSec=5s
```

Now that's it, you may want to run the command `systemctl daemon-reload` just to complement this.

You can then try rebooting or shutting down to confirm the change worked.

###### Bonus

If you want to set the maximum timeout for the entire system, you do so in the `/etc/systemd/system.conf` file.

Look for the line `DefaultTimeoutStopSec` and set it just as you did previously.

Comment: A couple of remarks: Systemd units normally reside inside `/lib/systemd/system/` - I'm pretty sure any `.service` file inside `/etc/systemd/system/` is a symlink that points to `/lib/systemd/system/`. And another thing: It's generally best to modify unit files by using drop-in configs. This means you should create the directory `/etc/systemd/system/redis.service.d`, and create a config file here (called `redis.conf`). And inside this file you would add the line `TimeoutStopSec=5s`. This means your custom config will survive if the unit file gets updated.

Comment: Sure, thanks for the tip.

Comment: `redis.service` links to `redis-server.service` in `/lib/systemd/system/`. With `/lib/` instead of `/etc/`, folder should be `/lib/systemd/system/redis-server.service.d/`

Answer (score 0):

check your /etc/redis/redis.log file for the reason why it cant restart.

For me, i had the following error:

```
1963:signal-handler (1670871763) Received SIGTERM scheduling shutdown...
1963:M 12 Dec 2022 14:02:43.145 # User requested shutdown...
1963:M 12 Dec 2022 14:02:43.145 * Saving the final RDB snapshot before 
exiting.
1963:M 12 Dec 2022 14:02:43.145 # Failed opening the temp RDB file temp-
1963.rdb (in server root dir /var/log) for saving: Read-only file system
1963:M 12 Dec 2022 14:02:43.145 # Error trying to save the DB, can't exit.
1963:M 12 Dec 2022 14:02:43.145 # Errors trying to shut down the server.
```

Check the logs for more information.

To fix it i just ran the following to fix the problem.

```
sudo chown redis /var/log/redis/redis.log && sudo chmod u+x /var/log/redis/redis.log
```